# Git Mergtool: No files need merging + git status all conflicts fixed

Tags: git, merge, mergetool

Recently my mergetool has been acting up any merge that has conflicts mergetool will report no files need merging and git status shows all conflicts are fixed. When they in fact are not.

Here is my global .gitconfig:

```
[core]
        excludesfile = /Users/xxx/.gitignore_global
        trustctime = false
[merge]
        tool = kdiff3
        conflictstyle = diff3
[mergetool]
        trustExitCode = true
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to figure out the root cause, I now mark all files as unresolved and do `git mergetool`

Answer (score 1):

This can sometimes happen when your merge tool (in this case, kdiff3) is more aggressive with merging than git is. So git tries to merge, and says "hmmm, I'm not quite sure how to do this, so mark it as conflicted". Then you open it in your merge tool, and it determines that it can indeed merge everything without human intervention, so it does immediately upon opening it, and your conflicts are merged. This is a *good* thing, so be happy :)

Comment: When I look at the conflicted files though there is definitely still conflicts I can see 'HEAD <<<<<' etc